# Indirect modification of overloaded element

Tags: php

I'm getting an error, never had before. I don't know the meaning exactly or how I can fix it

```
trait Test{

    function init(){
       $req = $this->getRequest();
       usort($req['topics], function($first, $next) {
          if(is_null($first['expiryDate'])) return 1;
          if(is_null($next['expiryDate'])) return -1;
          // otherwise ascending
         return $first['expiryDate'] > $next['expiryDate'];
       });
    }

}
```

this is my class

```
class SchedulerRepository extends Repository implements SchedulerInterface
{
    use Test;

    protected Collection $request;

    protected array $topics;

    /**
    * @return Collection
    */
    public function getRequest(): Collection
    {
       return $this->request;
    }

    public function bootstrap($data)
    {
        $this->request = $data;

        dd($this->init());
    }

}
```

The error i'm getting

```
"message": "Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\\Support\\Collection has no effect",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
```

the error is in my Trait exactly in the first parameter of `usort` function

I tried to Google the issue, but no luck

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast fix is to create a temporary variable based on the array index, sort that, and set it back. Also, comparison functions should return integers, not booleans, `<=>` should be used instead of `>`.

```php
trait Test {
    function init(){
       $req = $this->getRequest();
       $topics = $req['topics'];
       usort($topics, function($first, $next) {
          if(is_null($first['expiryDate'])) return 1;
          if(is_null($next['expiryDate'])) return -1;
          // otherwise ascending
         return $first['expiryDate'] <=> $next['expiryDate'];
       });
       $req['topics'] = $topics;
    }
}
```

You can see a mocked demo here: https://3v4l.org/qLN2l

The longer answer has to do with `Collection` which implements `ArrayAccess`. The latter interface allows user-land code to be interacted with using array-like semantics, specifically `[]`, through class methods. Anytime you see `[]` a call to `offsetGet` happens on the object, and this returns a *copy* of the array. The notice exists to warn you that your changes would be lost.